# Windows 10: Save and open windows have groups when windows explorer does not

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have my Windows Explorer set up so that files and folders are not grouped. However, whenever a save as dialog box comes up the files & folders are grouped and I cannot access the view menu like I can in the regular Windows Explorer. Can I fix this? Or is it a bug?

Windows Version 10.0.18356

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click in the background of the dialog and select **Group by > (None)** from the context menu:
[image]

Keith